# Multiple Filter Queries(fq) in SOLR

Tags: solr

I'm having my SOLR index as:

```
{'year':2002
'user_entries':['user1']},
{'year':2003
'user_entries':['user2']},
{'year':2002
'user_entries':['user1']},
```

Expected result

`{facet_fields:{2002:{'user1':2}, 2003:{'user2':1}}}`

I can use *fq=year:2002* to extract the facets on user_entries to extract the count of entries of each user in year 2002 as

> /solr/rss/select?q=*:*&fq=year:2002&wt=json&indent=true&facet=true&facet.query=year:2002&facet.field=user_entries

But I want to extract the user_entries of each year from: 2002 to 2010 individually without summing them all up.

#### Current Approach:

`1.    solr/rss/select?q=*:*&fq=year:2002&wt=json&indent=true&facet=true&facet.query=year:2002&facet.field=user_entries
2.    solr/rss/select?q=*:*&fq=year:2003&wt=json&indent=true&facet=true&facet.query=year:2003&facet.field=user_entries`...

So can I have a **single** multiple filter query instead of *multiple* queries for each year with which I can extract individual year data without summing them up as with default OR operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Solr 4.0 or newer then you can use [pivot facets](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/HierarchicalFaceting#Pivot_Facets):

```
?q=*:*
&facet=true
&facet.pivot=year,user_entries
&f.user_entries.facet.limit=3
```

But the response is not exactly the same as regular field facets, so you may have to change your parsing code. You will get the count for the "2002" value of the year field, and for each combination of "2002" and values of the user_entries fields (limited to 3), followed by the same for the "2003" value.

Comment: **Thanks** for your answer.Can I limit the number of user_entries in pivot result. Your query gives all user_entries of all years, but I just need top 3 user_entries of each year. When I use `facet.limit=3` then it limits both the years and user_entries which is not complete.

Comment: I have edited my answer to include a limit for a specific field.

Comment: The additional parameter `f.user_entries.limit=3` has no effect on result. It is still extracting all the user_entries of each year.

Comment: Sorry, the correct syntax is `f.{fieldname}.facet.limit`.

Comment: **THANKYOU very much MICHIELVOO**.

Comment: Is there anything like pivot query or something like facet query?

Comment: @user199354 You can look into [result grouping](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Result+Grouping): `q=*:*&group=true&group.field=year`. Maybe that is what you need? Otherwsie you should really create a new question, instead of using the comments.